# Is this a first Mars aerobraking for ESA, or for anyone?

Tags: mars, record, esa, aerobraking, exomars

In the ESA video [ExoMars at the Red Planet](http://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/Videos/2016/10/ExoMars_at_the_Red_Planet) after about 02:10, it says:

> With ExoMars, ESA is going to use for the first time, a method called aerobraking for a spacecraft in orbit around Mars...

Will this be:

1. the first time ESA has used aerobraking
2. the first time ESA has used aerobraking around Mars
3. the first time aerobraking has been used around MARS

or something else?

This video can be seen in YouTube:

Comment: The wikipedia article should answer your question and provide interesting facts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobraking

Comment: @Antzi it doesn't purport itself to be an up-to-date accurate, exhaustive, and curated list of all aerobraking maneuvers by spacecraft in history. I wanted to clarify the precise "first-ness" described in the video, and chose a real live expert in this case.

Comment: It does eliminate 1 and 3 options :)

Comment: @Antzi it takes a long time to sort through that article and piece that together, and there is no guarantee a given Wikipedia article is even correct. If it were an active list, labeled specifically *as a complete and updated list of all aerobraking maneuvers* and appeared to actually be actively curated and updated, that would be different. After all Wikipedia authors are only human. MarkAdler on the other hand... :-)

Comment: I would revolutionize aerobreaking for Mars. I believe the atmosphere of Mars can be skimmed using a special glider blimp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESA has done aerobraking with Venus Express. NASA has done aerobraking at Mars several times, as well as at Venus.  This will be the first time that *ESA* has done aerobraking at *Mars*.

Comment: OK, to double check: it's 2. the first time ESA has used aerobraking around Mars?

Comment: I could guess, but I need a `boolean`. This is ESA's first aerobraking at Mars?

Comment: Yes, Door number two.